# Doctrine returns many-to-many collection in incorrect order

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, many-to-many

I'm starting to struggle with finding a solution for this online/offline so maybe someone has an answer or suggestion of best approach.

The problem is that a `Question` entity has a many-to-many relation `tags` which should return `Tag` entities in alphabetical order. The generated SQL is correct, but the collection which is returned doesn't follow the order.

I'm starting to lean towards using:

a) lifecycle events to call a method which will sort the `tags` collection.

b) on `getTags()` method call a method which will check if collection was sorted (for performance to avoid multiple sorts) and then sort the collection if it's the first time.

**Does anyone know why collection is not sorted or which solution will be best?**

Some info of code:

Generated SQL

```
SELECT
    q0_.id AS id0,
    q0_.question AS question1, 
    t1_.id AS id2, 
    t1_.name AS name3 
FROM question q0_ 
LEFT JOIN questions_tags q2_ ON q0_.id = q2_.question_id 
LEFT JOIN tag t1_ ON t1_.id = q2_.tag_id 
ORDER BY
    q0_.question ASC, 
    t1_.name ASC
```

Available data

```
INSERT INTO `question` (`id`,`question`) VALUES (1,'Who are you?');
INSERT INTO `questions_tags` (`question_id`,`tag_id`) VALUES (1,1);
INSERT INTO `questions_tags` (`question_id`,`tag_id`) VALUES (1,2);
INSERT INTO `questions_tags` (`question_id`,`tag_id`) VALUES (1,3);
INSERT INTO `tag` (`id`,`name`) VALUES (1,'personal');
INSERT INTO `tag` (`id`,`name`) VALUES (2,'jobs');
INSERT INTO `tag` (`id`,`name`) VALUES (3,'achievements');
```

Partial dump of `getQuestions()` method

```
Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection {#3131
  -owner: AppBundle\Entity\Question {#3118
    -id: 1
    -question: "Who are you?"
    -tags: Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection {#3131}
  }
  -coll: Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection {#3127
    -_elements: array:3 [
      0 => AppBundle\Entity\Tag {#3121
        -id: 1
        -name: "personal"
      }
      1 => AppBundle\Entity\Tag {#3123
        -id: 2
        -name: "jobs"
      }
      2 => AppBundle\Entity\Tag {#3074
        -id: 3
        -name: "achievements"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Question entity

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use AppBundle\Entity\Tag;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Question
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="question")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\QuestionRepository")
 */
class Question
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="question", type="text")
     */
    private $question;

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tag", inversedBy="questions", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="questions_tags")
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"name"="ASC"})
     */
    private $tags;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->tags = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set question
     *
     * @param string $question
     * @return Question
     */
    public function setQuestion($question)
    {
        $this->question = $question;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get question
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getQuestion()
    {
        return $this->question;
    }

    /**
     * Add tags
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Tag $tags
     * @return Question
     */
    public function addTag(Tag $tags)
    {
        $this->tags[] = $tags;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove tags
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Tag $tags
     */
    public function removeTag(Tag $tags)
    {
        $this->tags->removeElement($tags);
    }

    /**
     * Get tags
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getTags()
    {
        return $this->tags;
    }
}
```

Tag entity

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Tag
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="tag")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\TagRepository")
 */
class Tag
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=128)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Question", mappedBy="tags")
     */
    private $questions;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->questions = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return Tag
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Add questions
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Question $questions
     * @return Tag
     */
    public function addQuestion(\AppBundle\Entity\Question $questions)
    {
        $this->questions[] = $questions;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove questions
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Question $questions
     */
    public function removeQuestion(\AppBundle\Entity\Question $questions)
    {
        $this->questions->removeElement($questions);
    }

    /**
     * Get questions
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getQuestions()
    {
        return $this->questions;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

QuestionRepository

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class QuestionRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    /** @return Question[] */
    public function getQuestions()
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('q')
            ->select(['q', 't'])
            ->leftJoin('q.tags', 't')
            ->orderBy('q.question', 'ASC')
            ->getQuery()
            ->execute()
        ;
    }
}
```

EDIT 2015-03-27:

For the time being I chose to extend the question entity with sort method:

```
<?php
// ...
class Question
{
    // ...

    /** @var boolean a flag to check if tags collection was sorted */
    private $isTagsSorted = false;

    // ...

    /**
     * Get tags
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getTags()
    {
        $this->sortTagsAlphabetically();

        return $this->tags;
    }

    /** @return void */
    private function sortTagsAlphabetically()
    {
        if ($this->isTagsSorted) {
            return;
        }

        $tags = $this->tags->toArray();

        usort($tags, function ($a, $b) {
            return $a->getName() > $b->getName();
        });

        $this->tags = new ArrayCollection($tags);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a subquery to achieve this, because the order by affect the main query so obviously it will try to order first by question it does it and then try to order the questions by tag (not the tags). So something like this should do it :

```
SELECT
    q0_.id AS id0,
    q0_.question AS question1, 
    t1_.id AS id2, 
    t1_.name AS name3 
FROM question q0_ 
LEFT JOIN questions_tags q2_ ON q0_.id = q2_.question_id 
LEFT JOIN (select * from tag t1_ ORDER BY t1_.name ) t1_ 
ON t1_.id = q2_.tag_id
ORDER BY
    q0_.question ASC, 
    t1_.name ASC
```

For the DQL i am sorry but i think you will have to do it the old fashion way NativeSql since doctrine doesnt support joining subqueries with dql :

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/doctrine-user/0rNbXlD0E_8/xMNiQgp9c3QJ

But nativesql would be fine :)  also :

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html

Just use the query i gave you, change it a bit to be readable then use :

```
$sql  = "your query"
$connection = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection();
$query = $connection->prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
$results = $query->fetchAll();
return $results;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yes it makes sense that it shorts questions by the tag and not tags.

Your solution solves the problem of getting tags in order by the few issues I have with it is what it's less readable (more complex) and to some extend you lose entities. For the time being I think I will stay with adding sorting with an extra method.

Answer (score 0):

The annotation of ordering is used only if the content is not already fetched, as example if you have fetch from the dm only the .. if you call the get.. method the result is sorted.

In your case, you get all the data in one shot, so the annotation doesn't work as expected.

In your case you can add a mehod in the `Tag` entity for sort the data on the fly, as example:

```
public function getSortedTags()
{
    $criteria = Criteria::create()
        ->orderBy(array("name" => Criteria::ASC));

    return $this->tags->matching($criteria);
}
```

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Did some testing and yes just calling `getTags()` returns it in sorted order. Unfortunately for some reason in Behat scenario which doesn't use web context they are not ordered.

Also I don't think your provided example will work in this case as it's many-to-many relation. The following exception is thrown `Matching Criteria on PersistentCollection only works on OneToMany associations at the moment.`

Comment: Hi @AndrewMarcinkevičius I missed the `PersistentCollection` scenario and (i tested i on a simple `ArrayCollection`) I see in the source code that is not possible use my solutions. In alternative you can sort getting the iterator and sort it but is not a great solutions (you need to build another collection..)